# How to use multi-inheritence with std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

So, I have code like this:

```
class IUpdatable {
    virtual void onUpdate() = 0;
};
class IDrawable {
    virtual void onDraw() = 0;
};
class IEventable {
    virtual void onEvent() = 0;
};

class IObject {};
class Button : public IObject, public IUpdatable, public IDrawable, public IEventable {/*override of virtual metothods*/};
class NonVisibleButton : public IObject, public IUpdatable, public IEventable {/*override of virtual methods*/}

int main(){
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr <IObject>> buttons = {
        new Button(),
        new NonVisibleButton()
    };
    std::vector <std::weak_ptr <IEventable>> eventables = {
        buttons.at(0),
        buttons.at(1)
    };
    std::vector <std::weak_ptr <IDrawble>> drawbles = {
        buttons.at(0)
    };
}
```

So, can I realize this and how? I want to regulary update vector with buttons in the different containers. (to be more precise, I have individual thread for updating IEventable's child class' objects and absolutely everything that inherits from IEventable goes here)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast ?

Comment: Aside: I don't think you need the do-nothing type `IObject`, you could use `std::shared_ptr<void>` in place of `std::shared_ptr<IObject>` if you use `std::make_shared`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class IUpdatable {
public:
    virtual void onUpdate() = 0;
};
class IDrawable {
public:
    virtual void onDraw() = 0;
};
class IEventable {
public:
    virtual void onEvent() = 0;
};

class IObject {
public:
    virtual ~IObject() = default;
};

class Button : public IObject, public IUpdatable, public IDrawable, public IEventable {
public:
    void onUpdate() override {}
    void onDraw() override {}
    void onEvent() override {}
};

class NonVisibleButton : public IObject, public IUpdatable, public IEventable {
public:
    void onUpdate() override {}
    void onEvent() override {}
};

int main(){
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr <IObject>> buttons = {
        std::static_pointer_cast<IObject>(std::make_shared<Button>()),
        std::static_pointer_cast<IObject>(std::make_shared<NonVisibleButton>())
    };
    std::vector <std::weak_ptr <IEventable>> eventables = {
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IEventable>(buttons.at(0)),
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IEventable>(buttons.at(1))
    };
    std::vector <std::weak_ptr <IDrawable>> drawbles = {
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IDrawable>(buttons.at(0))
    };
}
```

Honestly though, I wouldn't try to shoehorn a Java code structure (interfaces, inheritance, etc) into C++... Try [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) if possible.

Comment: Great answer. As an additional hint which might be moved into the answer: IObject needs to have atleast one virtual function to count as a polymorphic object and therefore be able to cast to it. As IObject represents the base class, the virtual destructor is choosen to guarantee a proper destruction of the subclass objects. As a cast operator dynamic_cast is used as we "move" within an inheritance. In this case from base to base.

Answer (score 0):

Use local variables to hold the `Button` and `NonVisibleButton`. That has the added benefit of not needing `buttons.at` to refer to them.

```
int main(){
    auto b = std::make_shared<Button>();
    auto nvb = std::make_shared<NonVisibleButton>();
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr <IObject>> buttons = {
        b,
        nvb
    };
    std::vector <std::weak_ptr <IEventable>> eventables = {
        b,
        nvb
    };
    std::vector <std::weak_ptr <IDrawble>> drawbles = {
        b
    };
}
```